How to make user can set their own domain that redirects to my server programatically?
I'm building a web builder. Currently, the user can create a static page and use our subdomain to access the page, such as mysite.site.domain.com.
I have a plan to allow user to use their own domain to be redirected to their page, how can I achieve this? Should I build a custom DNS? What is the concept behind this?
This app is deployed on the Ubuntu machine and Nginx webserver.

which domain provider does your client use, and are you using a cloud provider?

@masteronin99 My goal is to allow my app users to have flexible settings. So it will be better to allow this from any providers

I'm going to assume you are currently generating a static HTML file and then storing it somewhere on your server. After that, you generate a link to that page which is accessible from a subdomain. Again I assume you have a subdomain for each user/client.
In order to achieve your goal first your clients need to ask their domain provider to set their DNS to your website. The same way set your server IP for your domain.
Next, you need to dynamically generate nginx configs based on the client domain(a simple form to enter the domain). A simple script will do the trick. Pick any language you are familiar with and generate 2 configs files and put them accordingly in the following directories:

/etc/nginx/conf.d/example.com.conf
/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com

These configs are similar to other Nginx configs you already have for your own domain.
Some tips:

Check the user's domain's current DNS before proceeding. Run a whois on user's input to make sure their domain is set to your IP or Nameservers(NS)
Make sure to remove nginx config files if user removed their domain from your server. You can even run a job to check/whois domains in some time intervals(weekly for example)
In case you are not generating static files(HTMLs) and you are using a Next service and you don't want to change current routers or run multiple Next services you can simply use Nginx reverse proxy and add route prefixes.


Are there any other ways to do this without creating a custom script to modify the nginx config? and is there a cloud service that can do this for managing the DNS? i heard that Cloudflare has a service to do this, but I still don't understand on how it works.

@Regn you can redirect user's domain with some cloud providers like Cloudflare. But if you want to see user's domain in browser, as far as I know there is no way.
Even using Cloudflare you need to generate some configs its just different type of configs instead of Nginx configs.
DNS management will be done by Domain owner not you. You just need to provide a NS to your users so they can set it for their domain.

When I use Heroku, they allow users to connect their own domain by adding a CNAME record to Heroku DNS, how does this work, I mean, is adding a CNAME record to my website builder subdomain enough?
